# (A sequence that sum of km-th terms converges to 0) and (completely multiplicative sequence with sum 0)

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I tried to solve the following problem.

Problem : Is there $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ which is the sequence of real numbers s.t.

$\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{km} =0$ and $\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}^+ s.t. a_n\neq 0.$

And it's sure that any completely multiplicative function with sum 0 is the example of that problem.

The typical example of this problem is
$a_n = \frac {\lambda (n)}{n}$

where $\lambda$ is the completely multiplicative function equal to −1 on the prime numbers, i.e. Liouville function,  according to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04832.pdf

Well, I couldn't find how to prove that the sum of $\frac {\lambda (n)}{n}$ converges to 0. (Still curious how to prove the sum converges to 0.)

So, I tried to find another intentional and more intuitive sequence for that problem.

For that, I defined the completely multiplicative sequence $\{b_n\}$ like this.
I just need to define the function value of the prime numbers and 1.

$b_1=1, b_2=-\frac 1 2$

and for any prime p>2,

$b_p=-\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}b_k.$   i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{p}b_p=0$.

And $\{b_n\}$ is multiplicative.

Then,  $b_1=1, b_2=-\frac 1 2, b_3=-\frac 1 2, b_4=\frac 1 4, b_5=-\frac 1 4, \cdots$

It's sure that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$ converges, the value is 0.

I guess $\{b_n\}$ will be the answer, but unfortunately, handling $\{b_n\}$ was too tough for me.

And I calculated some 10^4 terms with a computer, it seems that $\{|b_n|\}$ converges pretty slowly if it converges.

So I have 2 questions related to this problem.

1. How can I prove or disprove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n=0$? Or what should I know for that?
2. Is there other example of the problem which isn't completely multiplicative?